# Set column value in pandas dataframe where both the cell and the value are conditional on an element in the row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({/
'Time': ['0','0','0','1','1','1','2','2','2'],/
'Animal': ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Pig', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Pig', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Pig'],/
'Displacement': ['1', '3', '2', '4', '2', '3', '1', '4', '6']/
})
```

I would like to add a new column called 'RelativeDisplacement', which has a value of displacement minus the value for displacement for the animal at time zero

I can make it work by iterating over the rows, e.g.

```
rDisplacement0 = df[df['Time']=='0'][df['Animal']=='Cat']['Displacement'][0]

rDisplacements = []

for row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1]['Animal'] == 'Cat':
    
        rDisplacements.append(row[1]['Displacement'] - rDisplacement0 )
```

But this doesn't seem like a nice solution. I'm sure there will be a good vectorised way of doing this but I can't work it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values as time 0:

```
# ensure integers for arithmetic
df['Displacement'] = df['Displacement'].astype(int)

df['RelativeDisplacement'] = (
    df['Displacement']
    .sub(df['Animal'].map(df.loc[df['Time'].eq('0')]
                            .set_index('Animal')['Displacement']))
```

Or, if the times are sorted in ascending order, using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['RelativeDisplacement'] = df['Displacement'].sub(df.groupby('Animal')['Displacement'].transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
  Time Animal  Displacement  RelativeDisplacement
0    0    Cat             1                     0
1    0    Dog             3                     0
2    0    Pig             2                     0
3    1    Cat             4                     3
4    1    Dog             2                    -1
5    1    Pig             3                     1
6    2    Cat             1                     0
7    2    Dog             4                     1
8    2    Pig             6                     4
```